# Can I grow a Bird of Paradise in Bangladesh?

Tags: flowers, plant-care

[image: bird of paradise]

I love the bird of paradise flower. It's my dream to have it on my balcony. Here in Bangladesh the average temperature in summer is 33 - 36 Celsius. In winter it is 26 Celsius. Can I fulfil my dream?

Answer (score 2):

You can grow Strelitzia reginae in Bangladesh in a pot or outdoors.

[It has been widely introduced around the world, including the Americas
 and Australia, growing well in any area that is sunny and warm.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strelitzia_reginae)

It is also known as the bird of paradise and is comparatively easy to grow in full sun to semi shade. It flowers on a seasonal basis and is drought tolerant once established. A rich loamy soil and regular feeding with compost or fertilizer will encourage flowering. This plant does not tolerate frost but will benefit from cooler night temperatures.

The guides say this plant is wind resistant but indoors where I saw it the leaves tended to look a bit tattered as people going by it would cause tears in the leaf. Susceptible to mealy bug and false scale. The large leaves make pest control easier unless the pest can hide in the axils of the leaf sheathes.[[1]](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/a/8741/499)

This plant is fairly slow growing and will not flower for three to five years after planting.

See [here](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/8686/identify-this-insect-or-fungus-possible-scale/8687#8687) for more detail on possible pests and control methods.

You average daytime temperatures in the 30 degree Celsius range are hard on new plants and you should water new plants generously until they are established.

Comment: Thank u very much kevinsky. I am really happy to know I can grow bird of paradise in this climate. I am trying to find this plant. Its rare in Bangladesh. Hanging lobsters claw is pretty available. Its called false bird of paradise right?

Comment: @trina yes, the false bird of paradise is also called the hanging lobster claw and is also suitable for your area.

Answer (score 0):

It surely is possible to grow here in Bangladesh. Temperature/Rainfall in Dhaka City appears to be suitable for it. I have seen this and taken a photo of it. Its in Road-18, Block-J, Banani. Here is a snapshot[image]

Comment: Some more text could help other people to find your answer.

Comment: Does does not directly answer the question that is being posed.  Can Bird of Paradise be grown in the region and temperature conditions specified in the question?